# Have a loop with return value in getter/ setter C# property

Tags: c#

I need to get the count of Employment for each Applicant in C# property, this is my code:

I am getting this error that not all the path return value what I need to change.

```
public class Application
{
    public int NumberOfEmpl {
        get
        {              
            foreach (var item in Applicants)
            {
                return Applicants == null ? 0 : (item.Employments.Count);
            }
        }
        set {}
    }
}
```

Comment: No idea what you are trying to do, but there are tons of questions about this error.

Comment: Don't make empty `set` accessors.

Comment: `Applicants` cannot be null inside the loop.

Comment: Aside from your misspelled error being easy to find information on, your code doesn't make any sense. Why would you want to return a value within a loop? Once you return a value, the getter terminates. That means you have a loop that could only every iterate once.

Answer (score 2):

As the error is trying to tell you, you need to make sure your property *always* returns a value – even if the collection is empty.